# Transparency and SF beta 4

Tags: sifr

I'm implementing sirf in a site using a Drupal module. I have a few issues...

1. During testing the text fails in Safari 4 beta (win) and renders with a green background when transparency is applied. No doubt a Safari or plug in issue. There are a few crap things happening, the Lightbox overlay fails to cover any Flash objects. I'm sure you guys are tracking that error.
2. Exported fonts using Flash CS4 don't work. Got no idea why, I reverted to using one of the online conversion sites. I think the FLA is CS3. Maybe this could be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Transparency failing in Safari 4 / Windows in definitely a Safari bug.

Which sIFR version are you using? The sIFR 2 movie is available in a CS 3 format, I do think the sIFR 3 movie is Flash 8.

Answer (score 0):

sIRF3 and not working with Flash CS4 (for editing)

I've got some issues with headings not being drawn on the initial page load. Like the heading aren't draw in html before sIRF starts up and nothing then appears.

And another where jQuery created drop shadows draw before the sIRF text then when the page shifts they are in the wrong location.

I've mutated the call to this...

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  $('.image-thumbnail img').ready(function(){
    setTimeout( "drawShadow();", 4000) //slow it down to give objects a chance to draw
  });
});


function drawShadow(){
  $('.image-thumbnail').dropShadow({left:2, top:2, blur:2, opacity:0.5});  // Creates new drop shadows
}
```

What I really need is a signal that sIRF has completed. Any clue how I might do that?